# mocking SFTP using MUNIT

Tags: mocking, sftp, munit

I have already seen the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222864/how-to-fake-sftp-server-on-mule-unit-test), but the links provided in the answer are not working now. so seriously needed a solution for this issue.

I have an SFTP setup in my mule flow along with a Database. I need to mock the SFTP and test my mule flow using MUNIT. Can you please share some steps on how to proceed for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please take a look at the documentation in this link: https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.2.0/munit-ftp-server
HTH

Comment: Thans Dds. Its really helpful.